# Dlls are copied at each build

Tags: visual-studio-2012, build, nuget

I have a c# project, that is using nuget-packages, for instance "System.Data.SQLite".
When I build my solution, the project is built each time.

Looking into details, it turns out that the DLLs that belong to packages (that are located in

```
$(SolutionDir)\packages\$(PackageName)\
```

) will be renewed before each build, although there is no new version on the server. This results into this each-time-building.

How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded nuget.exe to v2.7 solved the problem